# Conditional to detect mobile devices with getUserAgent?

Tags: conditional, array, contains

I want to create a User Agent check. (Yes I know. It is evil.)

So I created an Array. The whole idea is to see if the user agent contains a specific word. This way I hope to circumvent regex trickery. But I have a hard time figuring how to return `true` only once:

This would be the array:

```
{% set browserValues = [ { agent: 'android'}, { agent: 'iemobile'} {# and so on #}]
```

This is how I get the user agent:

```
{% set userAgent = craft.request.getUserAgent()|lower %}
```

I came this far:

```
 {% for item in browserValues %}
   {% if item.agent in userAgent %}
     You're on mobile
   {% else %}
     You're not on mobile
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

This actually works. But there are two problems: If the conditional is false (not on mobile), the conditional is applied for each key in the array. `You're not on mobile You're not on mobile You're not on mobile`

If the user agent string contains the word `android` twice the conditional is applied twice.

How can I prevent the conditional from looping over and over? (My brain starts to loop over and over too).

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike in PHP, it's not actually possible to break a `for` loop in Twig.

To work around that fact, you can use the `for` loop to set a flag, and then put the conditional outside the loop:

```
{% set isUserOnMobile = false %}

{% for item in browserValues %}
    {% set isUserOnMobile = not isUserOnMobile ? item.agent in userAgent : isUserOnMobile %}
{% endfor %}

{% if isUserOnMobile %}
    You're on mobile
{% else %}
    You're not on mobile
{% endif %}
```

Another option: I actually wrote a plugin called [Detect](https://github.com/mmikkel/Detect-Craft) for device detection (the plugin wraps the excellent [Mobile_Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) library, which is sponsored by BrowserStack). Might be you'll be be able to use that, instead of hard coding lots of user agent strings. Here's how you can use Detect in a template:

```
{% set isUserMobile = craft.detect.isMobile %}
{% set isUserTablet = craft.detect.isTablet %}
{% set isUserPhone = craft.detect.isPhone %}
{% set isUserIphone = craft.detect.is('iphone') %}
{% set userAgent = craft.detect.getUserAgent %}
```

Comment: +1 for using a plugin for this problem.

Comment: Is there a way to check if this is an iPhoneX (as opposed to other versions of iPhone)? I tried {{ craft.mobileDetect.version('iPhone') }} but just get a 1. Thanks.